# SQLite transaction not committed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, commit

I use SQLite in my application.
The database works fine.
I can insert, select and update the rows, but in this one case the transaction is not committed.

```
public int updateTransaction(String oldstatus, String newstatus) {
    int result;
    try {
        mDB.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("trx_status", newstatus);
        result = mDB.update("transaktion", values, "trx_status = ?", new String[] { oldstatus });
        Log.d("DB", "updateTransaction:number of updated rows:" + result);
        mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("TAGAB", "Error:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        result = -1;
    } finally {
        mDB.endTransaction();
    }

    Log.d("TAGAB", "in Transaction? " + mDB.inTransaction());
    return result;
}
```

In LogCat:

```
"TAGAB" in Transaction? true
```

The updates are initially preformed and, if I select the rows, I receive the rows with the new status.

After the application is closed  and started again, the rows have the old status again!
Is the transaction rolled back? If so, why?
The database is defined as singleton.

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
private static DatabaseAdapter INSTANCE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "inTransaction true" hints that you have an outer transaction where this inner transaction is nested in.

Everything works fine when querying the data within the ongoing transaction.

Android sqlite has only partial support for nested transactions. What happens to the outermost transaction decides what happens to all the nested transactions.

In your case the outermost transaction gets rolled back and any changes in the nested transactions get rolled back, too.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer! I havn't any other transaction started. This is the single transaction.

Comment: Then the outer transaction is started by something else - where are you calling the method from?

Comment: This method is called from any Activity after save button is clicked:

DatabaseAdapter da = DatabaseAdapter.getInstance(null, dummyPassword");
int result = da.updateTransaction("U", "T");
// the rows are successfully updatet

Comment: Solved !
You were right. Paralell was still one transaction open. After i close it the database works fine.
Thanks